# iTunes Order Songs by Unchecked

Tags: itunes, ipod

My wife unchecked a large number of songs in iTunes. She did this to help fit music on her nano. Unfortunately, in the process she has caused a lot of the songs that would normally be synced to my iPod to not be. Is there a way to order my library so that all of the unchecked songs are grouped together and I can determine what needs to be checked without have to scroll through every song?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are better off selecting everything (Cmd-A), then right-clicking on one of the selected songs and choosing "Check Selection".  Then your wife can set up a playlist that fits on her Nano and sync only that.

If she would like to just *exclude* certain songs and get all the rest on her Nano, she can use the following trick: First make a playlist named "Excluded" and add the undesired songs to it.  Then make a smart playlist using the criterion "Playlist is not Excluded".  Sync the latter to the Nano.

Comment: +1: Clever answer, I didn't know that iTunes could make smart playlists based off being checked or not.

Answer (score 3):

Make two smart playlists:

- Checked Songs: no matches, check "Match only checked items"
- Unchecked Songs: Match "Playlist" "is not" "Checked Songs"

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to make seperate playlists for your wife and yourself, then just set your ipod to sync the appropriate playlist and your wife's nano to hers. Just an idea.